# Return function data to django template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Was an error with the API. However, didn't throw back any errors.

Comment: I don't understand your code, can you make sure the indentation is correct? Your `def get_context_data()` method does nothing (because of `pass`) and the 3 lines at the bottom of your code snippet are not part of any function so this would crash.

Comment: Sorry. The person who made the edit added a pass, which i didn't notice. Updated.

Comment: you're setting `kwargs['test']` to be a function, not the result of that function. Anyway, what is `client` in the first place? What are these "events" you're talking about?

Comment: Hi @dirkgroten apologies for the lack of context. I've updated my code to make it a little cleaner. I'll provide some more info. I'm using the following: https://github.com/ettoreleandrotognoli/python-ami as I'm accessing call information from a PBX. I've obtained a list of callers using an Action. Within each Action, there are multiple events. I can retrieve and print the events inside the console / shell. However, I need to pass them to display these items to the template in Django.

Comment: 'add_event_listener' will retrieve the events and pass them to the function 'event_notification'. I then want to pass that data to the template.

Comment: I'm not sure how events are generated and "listened to". Is this asynchronous? In this case I don't understand what you're trying to do. A view's processing is synchronous: A user requests a page, the view passes variables to the template rendering engine and the rendered template is passed to the HTTP response. Adding an event listener sounds like it's going to wait for events to happen and later, when an event happens, trigger the callback function (event_notification). Please explain what the purpose of your view is and what the user is supposed to see. Give us the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1):

As [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) suggest, it is better to extend / add custom data to context, rather than re-implementing it:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['test'] = event_notification(source, event)
    return context
```

Also, as `event_notification` is callable, you need to resolve it and pass result of the function to template (or template can call callables, but without arguments; or you can use custom template tags).